# how do checkout the commits from specific user in git?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

In git, If I pushed few time of changes to remote repository, like following commits(commit A0001,commit A0002,commit A0005,commit A0006,commit A0008,).

And meanwhile, others also commit commit A0003,A0004, A0007, A0009.

And now I want to pull out those changes that only being pushed by me. 
How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "checkout"? Are you actually asking to rewrite history?

Comment: i wanna git pull the version that only contain changes pushed by me

Comment: In other words, you want a branch that rewrites history to only have those changes.  Use `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --author="connie" --format=%h` will give you all the commit hashes that connie commited.

Now when you say "checkout" I assume you mean you want these changes - that is my assumption.  If so, you can bring those changes into your own branch by copying the list found in the previous command, and putting them into a single line like

> commit1 commit2 commit3 ...

Now just cherry pick them all in a single command: `git cherry-pick <commit1> <commit2> <commit3> ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git log --author="John"`
where you can replace John by your git username.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: i want to pull our the change that only being made by me